# What is the meaning of this error?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

What is the meaning of this error?

> vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

Comment: -1 because author took no effort to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you to use the `dmesg` command to read the logs and find if there are any message that tells you something went wrong with `vboxdrv` and then act according to what they suggest. Of course if you don't understand this initial message, using `dmesg` won't get you very far because this is the next level in error messages.

On Ubuntu, you can more easily see vbox-related system messages using `journalctl -f` in a terminal and try to start VBox again (in another terminal).

For some background:

VBox requires a kernel driver (the `modprobe` command above is trying to load it). This kernel driver is normally compiled to match your current kernel. If you upgrade the kernel, a framework called DKMS automatically recompiles it to match the new kernel. So you can have a missing driver or a driver that no longer matches your kernel or your driver croaked on load for some reason (no support for current CPU and/or BIOS...) .